# Is "what a badass of a barber!" correct?

Tags: adjectives

If one wants to informally exclaim about the excellence of someone, say a barber, using the word *badass*, should one say "What a badass of a barber!"? Or is "What a badass barber!" more correct? Are both correct enough? Are there other alternatives one should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely "What a badass barber!" The alternative sounds strange.

In informal conversation, "badass" is often used as a adjective, referring to something that has the qualities of a badass. For example: "What a badass librarian!" or "Wow, that sales presentation was so badass!"

You can also use it as a noun: "That fisherman is **a** badass."

Either usage is grammatically correct; but for the specific sentence you're inquiring about, you should definitely use "What a badass barber."